# Can't create same id another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.3.8.
I'm trying to create same id another model in an action.

```
def create
  id = params[:id]
  item_master = ItemMaster.new(params[:item_master)
  item_master.id = id
  item_master.save
  item_master_child = ItemMaster.new(params[:item_master_child])
  item_master_child.id = id
  item_master_child.save
  p item_master
  # => ItemMaster id: 654, style: 6, icon: 7
  p item_master_child
  # => ItemMasterChild id: 654, sub_style: 4, roll: 5
end
```

It seems that save finished successfully, but actually item_master params becomes id: 654, style: 0, icon :0. All params except id becomes 0.
Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you should check the params hash on the server log. Maybe the params aren't being passed as you expect.

Comment: have a look at your ```log/development.log``` to see what is happening on the database level!

Comment: Since you set the id manually, the above doesn't say that save was successful or not. You need to examine return values from `save` calls or use `save!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probrem is can't mass-assign ID attriburtes, since it is protected attributes.
I've solved this way.

Make new ItemMaster and set only id attribute and save.
Make new ItemMasterChild with post params and set id attibute and save.
Then, update ItemMaster attibutes by post atttributes,this works fine.

Updating attibutes should be after save item_master_child.
If put it after item_master.save, the attributes are set as 0.
I don't know why....

```
def create
  id = params[:id]
  item_master = ItemMaster.new
  item_master.id = id
  item_master.save
  item_master_child = ItemMaster.new(params[:item_master_child])
  item_master_child.id = id
  item_master_child.save
  item_master.update_attributes(params[:item_master])
end
```

Thanks for all your support and replies.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
item_master_child.id = item_master.id
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Rails won't let you assign stuff to the database object's id field.
If you need to connect them somehow, then add a foreign key with a 'has_one' relationship, or belongs_to